# Are there any stations other than W1AW that fall under 47 CFR 97.113(a)(3)(iv)?

Tags: united-states, legal, fcc, arrl

[47 CFR 97.113](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97/subpart-B/section-97.113)(a)(3) normally prohibits amateurs from transmitting

> [c]ommunications in which the station licensee or control operator has a pecuniary interest, including communications on behalf of an employer.

However, 47 CFR 97.112(a)(3)(iv) allows

> [t]he control operator of a club station... [to] accept compensation for the periods of time when the station is transmitting telegraphy practice or information bulletins, provided that the station transmits such telegraphy practice and bulletins for at least 40 hours per week; schedules operations on at least six amateur service MF and HF bands using reasonable measures to maximize coverage; where the schedule of normal operating times and frequencies is published at least 30 days in advance of the actual transmissions; and where the control operator does not accept any direct or indirect compensation for any other service as a control operator.

This seems to basically be a long-winded way of saying "W1AW operators can be paid to send code practice," without naming a particular station. Are there any stations other than W1AW that meet these requirements?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149782/discussion-on-question-by-someone-are-there-any-stations-other-than-w1aw-that-fa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.